# MKDocs rendering apostrophes in Markdown as â€™

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I am creating an [MKDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) 1.4.3 (running on Python 3.11.2) static site with the [MKDocs Material](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/) theme.

The strange thing is that apostrophes like `'` are being rendered as `â€™` when I serve the rendered site locally with the `mkdocs serve` command.

For example, here's a snippet of my Markdown source:

```
## What is a container?

Let's consider the analogy of shipping containers that are used throughout the world.
```

This renders as:

[image: MKDocs rendering error]

Where you can see `let's` is shown as `letâ€™s`.

Similarly, double quotes are rendered as `â€œ`.

**What might be causing this strange phenomenon and how do I fix it?**

Thank you.

Comment: you're reading UTF-8 incorrectly as ISO 8859-1. Set the encoding correctly

Comment: Thanks @phuclv, but what does this mean and where/how do I set this encoding? Happy to upvote a specific answer.

Comment: Solution found here: 
https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/discussions/3329